# How do I flag a character string from a different language or a different unicode block so it renders correctly in the browser?

Tags: html, caching, unicode, preload, unicode-string

I have an HTML file created in VSC. It has a string of Bengali near the top of the page.
When opened in Chrome, sometimes (seemingly randomly) the Bengali suddenly renders as Chinese and question marks:
"爨踶�爨��爨� 爨伍�爨��爨��爨�爨� ..."
The original text string is Bengali:
"একবার স্বামীজি ট্রেনে করে যাচ্ছিলেন, তিনি সন্যাসীদের গেরুয়া..."
Strangely, even standard letters become corrupted, from:
"Ēkbár sbámīji ṭrēnē karē yácchilēn, tini sanyasi’s"
to:
"���kb叩r sb叩m朝ji 畊�r�n� kar� y叩cchil�n, tini sanyasi��s  
Even without making any changes, sometime later, it may open correctly! It seems to depend on the cache. If I include an English sentence before the Bengali in the same character string the whole thing renders perfectly. If I use an online compiler (with the same chrome browser) it also renders perfectly (without changing anything in the HTML).
Is there some means of flagging the Bengali unicode block and including the alphabet in the cache within my HTML to ensure this doesn't happen?

Comment: Please, first try the search function, there are a lot of such questions here. Have you tried setting this: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` ?

Comment: Thank you, DanielD, that solves that problem.

Answer (score 0):

DanieD has correctly indicated that the problem is resolved with the meta tag indicating utf-8 encoding.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```